# How to sum 1 specific column from a userform listbox to display in a textbox on same form

Tags: ms-access, listbox, ms-access-2010

I have been trying for several hours to resolve my problem myself but with no luck.

The controls I have are as follows

Userform - [frm_Team_View]
Listbox - [lst.Team] (column 0=Name, column 1=Initials, column 2=manager, column 3=hours worked)

I am trying to calculate the total hours worked for the whole team and display this in textbox - [txt_THours].

I have tried to do this in VBA using DSUM & SUM
I have also tried the same methods using the Control Source.

```
txt_THours.Value = Sum(Forms![frm_Team_View]![lst_Team].column(3))
```

Each time I keep getting a #Error message displayed in the textbox.

I managed to get a count of the rows in the listbox by using the `.listcount` function. I have not been able to find a function to sum the values.

The Query is run directly from the listbox so is not saved seperatly. I am unable to save the query seperatly as this will not allow other functionality I have on the userform.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: as previously discussed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve this question after several hours.
Please see below

```
txt_THours = DSum("[Hrs]", "Manager_Query")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to sum the values in a listbox with an expression.

I assume you build the `RowSource` of the listbox dynamically? When you do this, save the WHERE clause in a variable, and use the same WHERE clause in a `DSum` expression for the textbox.

Or run a VBA loop over the rows after setting the RowSource, but that seems a little silly.

```
For i = 0 To Me.lst_Team.ListCount - 1
    mySum = mySum + Me.lst_Team.Column(3, i)
Next i
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't work. However I resolved this myself